# PHP|MYSQL Query : compare two table fields and insert|overwrite value of one field if matches

Tags: php, mysql

I've got 2 tables :

- `jos_tempcsv`, which contains among others the following field: `Category of goods`
- `jos_categories`, which contains among others the following fields: `Category_id`, `slug`

I would like to create the following query:

I've got a table called `jos_tempcsv` which contains a field called `Category of goods`. This field contains alphanumeric values that needs to be changed in a numeric value.

I need to compare the value of the `Category of goods` field of the `jos_tempcsv` table with the value of the `slug` field of the `jos_categories` table.

If comparison matches, then I would like to insert the value contained in the `Category_id` field of the `jos_categories` table into the `Category of goods` field of the `jos_tempcsv` table (it should overwrite the initial value with a numeric value).

Comment: ok. So what you tired so far??

Comment: you can call two diif query to get rows from two diff table select only Category of goods from table 1 and slug from table2 compare these two variable using php array function array_diff [link] (http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_diff.asp)

Comment: @Abdulla, Thank you, you're great !

Comment: @PRANAV thank you for your explaination, it helps and I'll get back to you when it is done. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Find a solution which works, record are updated|overwritten :

```
$sql = "update jos_tempcsv u left join jos_virtuemart_categories_fr_fr c on c.slug=u.`Category of goods` set u.`Category of goods`=c.virtuemart_category_id;

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Thank you to @PRANAV and a special thanks to @Abdulla which has a great sens of humor